# Groovy Loop through SELECT and amend checkboxes

Tags: javascript, loops, select

I have a select with three options, and multiple checkboxes.

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="option1">Option 1</option>
<option value="option2">Option 2</option>
<option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<div>
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="checkbox1">Checkbox 1
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="checkbox2">Checkbox 2
<input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" value="checkbox3">Checkbox 3
</div>
```

I'd like to change which checkboxes are visible based on the options that are selected in the select, using Groovy.

For example, if option1 is selected, only checkbox1 should show. If option1 and option3 are selected, checkbox1 and checkbox3 should show. The ID's won't always match (eg. option1 might show checkbox3 rather than checkbox1 if I wanted it to).

I presume I'm going to need some kind of mapping table for the options against the checkboxes, and then loop through the options and show the correct checkboxes.

I can do it with multiple if statements (if mySelect equals option1 then show X etc) but multiple if statements will be very ugly. If there is a better way of doing this with a loop I'd appreciate the guidance.

Thanks

Comment: How is this related to groovy? Do you generate the HTML with the MarkupBuilder or is this Grails?  Please add what code generates above code so we can improve from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:-

HTML - add a class to the checkboxes wrapper

```
<div class="checkbox-container">
    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="checkbox1">Checkbox 1
    <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="checkbox2">Checkbox 2
    <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" value="checkbox3">Checkbox 3
</div>
```

JS

```
const selectEelement = document.getElementById("mySelect");

selectEelement.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var selectedValue = selectEelement.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var checkboxId = `checkbox${selectedValue.substr(selectedValue.length-1)}`;

    // First hide all the checkboxes
    document.querySelector('.checkbox-container').style.visibility = "hidden";

    // then show a particular checkbox
    document.getElementById(checkboxId).style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

Comment: @Jamie, does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you. It almost answers the question. There are still two things it doesn't do: 1. It doesn't change the checkbox automatically as different select options are selected. Only on page load. 2. The checkbox ID it shows corresponds to the select ID. For example, if option1 is selected, checkbox1 is shown. But this could easily be checkbox2 that needs to be shown... imagine there isn't a number in the ID. It could be called anything, so I imagine I need to build some kind of relationship table to tell the script which checkboxes to show for each select option?

Comment: Which two things? Can you please mention, if I missed something in question.

Comment: @JamieH For your first point, I have updated the answer. Basically you need to add an eventListener to the dropdown to detect the change. For you 2nd point, you are correct, you need to have some kind of mapping that you can put in option elements as values and then use the same while showing the particular checkboxes.

Comment: @JamieH Please accept this as an answer if, it answers your question. So that it can help other people as well. Thanks!